# Set language type in pattern - vs code language extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want for vscode to understand that the language in between `<go>` tags in a html file should be validated as golang code.

So given:

```html
<go>
    // I want to get intellisense and syntax highlighting for golang here
</go>
```

I currently have the following insides `grammars` in `package.json`:

```
{
    "scopeName": "go.html.injection",
    "path": "./syntaxes/go.tmLanguage.json",
    "injectTo": [
        "text.html"
    ],
    "embeddedLanguages": {
        "source.go": "go"
    }
}
```

and in `syntaxes/go.tmLanguage.json`:

```
{
    "scopeName": "go.html.injection",
    "injectionSelector": "L:text.html",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#go-tag"
        }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "go-tag": {
            "begin": "<go>",
            "end": "<\/go>",
            "name": "go"
        }
    }
}
```

Inspecting it using the debug gives it the name *go* as a textmate scope but the language is still set to *html*. How can I set the language of the match to golang:

[image: result of the debugger]

Inspecting the content of script tags show the language set to javascript so this should be possible? I also realise that then the match includes the `<go>` tag so I understand I now need to add pattern matching and evaluation for that.

#### Update 20/02/20:

After referring to the [vscode svelte extension](https://github.com/UnwrittenFun/svelte-vscode/blob/master/syntaxes/svelte.tmLanguage.json) I figured out how to get syntax highlighting for the tag and innerHTML using this inside `syntaxes/go.tmLanguage.json` (same `package.json`):

```
{
    "scopeName": "go.html.injection",
    "injectionSelector": "L:text.html",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#go-tag"
        }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "go-tag": {
            "begin": "(<)(go)",
            "beginCaptures": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html"
                },
                "2": {
                    "name": "entity.name.tag.html"
                },
                "3": {
                    "name": "punctuation.definition.tag.end.html"
                }
            },
            "end": "(<\/)(go)(>)",
            "endCaptures": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html"
                },
                "2": {
                    "name": "entity.name.tag.html"
                },
                "3": {
                    "name": "punctuation.definition.tag.end.html"
                }
            },
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "contentName": "source.go",
                    "begin": "(>)",
                    "beginCaptures": {
                        "1": {
                            "name": "punctuation.definition.tag.end.html"
                        }
                    },
                    "end": "(?=</go>)",
                    "patterns": [
                        {
                            "include": "source.go"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I can now see that vscode is correctly highlighting syntax for the tag and using the imported golang syntax tokens. **However** it is still displays the language as "html".

[image: new token debug screen]

Comment: This seems relevant: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47288

Comment: `embeddedLanguages` maps a textMateScope to a language. Does this work if you change the mapping to: `"go": "go"`? Also note that embedded languages will not enable intellisense, it just makes sure VS Code uses the correct style for basic language features such as comments

Comment: @MattBierner I understand where you are coming from as my left side of the map did not match the value of `name`. Unfortunately changing just changing the key had no effect. After a bit of "research" I have managed to get the syntax highlighting to work (see update). Somehow through `include` and `contentName` it seems to be working as intended. Can't find any vscode api docs on those keywords though?....

Comment: ...That is a little unintuitive that "intellisense features" are not implemented alongside syntax highlighting. I guess to get it to display the language property I have to do something else? any ideas on what that is? Would it be to repurpose a golang language server? Is that possible to do on a extended language?

Comment: Syntax highlighting + embedded languages is covered in https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide